# Variable assigned through Console.ReadLine() doesn't store "\n" correctly

Tags: c#, variables, newline

So i want to get text from the Console which includes special characters like \n and \t and when I write the text to the console then instead of a new line it displays \n.

Example

```
string x = "yes \n";
string y = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Input: `yes \n`

Output:

```
yes
yes \n
```

Any ideas on how to read special characters from the Console?

Comment: I don't think you get that output from the code shown

Answer (score 0):

Check your value when you debug and you'll see that `y` is `"yes \\n"`.

That's because `\n` is not a special character, it is an escape character. The definition itself, means that in order for c# to store the string `"\n"` as it was written by the user, it had to escape the `\` by adding another one.

Comment: Is there any way of reading such character from the console the way i would want? So \n would make a new line

Comment: Use the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape` function in the input.

Comment: No, the C# code doesn't do any escaping at execution time. It's that the compiler *reads* the escape sequence in the string literal when it reads source code - but the escape sequence is only *relevant* in source code. Yes, the debugger will show an escaped version, but I think it's misleading to give the impression that the string data itself is somehow escaped. If the user typed in `"yes \n"` at the console, the string will contain 6 characters, ending with a backslash and then an `n`. There's no doubling of the backslash in the string.

Answer (score -1):

so you should check if your string has `\\n` then split string with `\\n`, split method will return array of strings so we will for loop in this array

```cs
string x = "yes \n";
string y = Console.ReadLine();
if (y.Contains("\\n")) {
   string[] ySplit = y.Split("\\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < ySplit.Length; i++) {
       Console.WriteLine(ySplit[i]);
   }
 } else {
     Console.WriteLine(y);
 }
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. I believe the OP wants a string that contains a line feed character when they type `\n` in the console.

Comment: ooh, yes I am sorry but you can not change it in runtime

Comment: Well, you sort of can: `string y = Console.ReadLine().Replace("\\n", "\n");` would be fine, for example.

Comment: "no, this will do nothing" - um, it really will. Moreover, my version puts the line feed wherever the `\n` was, whereas your new version *always* puts it at the end. An input of `abc\ndef\nghi` should split it into three lines, whereas your will display "abcdefghi" and then a line feed. Also, your new version doesn't print *anything* unless the input contains `\n`.

Comment: so, we can use split method to make a newline

Comment: Why bother with that, when the replace call I showed in my earlier comment works perfectly well? This is pointlessly complex.

Comment: I know your code is highly customizable but when I tried it it didn't work for me I don't know why, you can consider my code as the second way :)

Comment: I tested my code and it definitely *did* work, so I would suggest you may have tried something slightly different. Here's the complete program: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/c11ebe3e68f3f312e95d582969a0c2c8